# How do I make a button be activated with either a click or the ENTER key in JavaFx?

Tags: java, button, javafx, click, enter

I know I can make an event go off by pressing the ENTER key with:

```
@FXML
private void event(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.ENTER)){
        guardarCambios();
        btnVolver.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

My question is: Is there any way for the event to work with either the ENTER key being pressed, or the button/item being clicked?

Thank you.

Comment: You can set a default button to respond to enter key : see [setDefaultButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html#setDefaultButton-boolean-)

Comment: `Button.onAction`

Comment: Thank you, but this was not helpful. I need more detail.